# Transact-SQL script equivalent to the option: Apply Tracked Changes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

Could anybody tell me what is the transact equivalent script of using the: Apply Tracked Changes menu?

[image: FullTex Index menu -> Apply Tracked Changes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an interesting discussion about this here:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1480807-2799-1.aspx

and I reckon that you will find everything you need here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Basically it seems to be something like:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [table_name] START UPDATE POPULATION
```